# How to calculate size of scatter plot's marker in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I create a simple matplotlib scatter plot.

How would I then draw the line between the edges of dots on scatter plot? Meaning that the line would start and end on edges of dots?

EDIT: Forgot to add code snippet

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.scatter([0, 0, 0], [5, 3, 4], s=250)
plt.scatter([3, 3, 3], [5, 3, 4], s=350)

plt.arrow(0, 5, dx=3, dy=0, width=0.01)
plt.arrow(0, 3, dx=3, dy=0, width=0.01)
plt.arrow(0, 4, dx=3, dy=0, width=0.01)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I subtract from dx to connect dots only from edges

Comment: Include a sketch of what you want to accomplish. Currently your question is not only too broad without any code or data, but also vague and unclear. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What you're asking for is pretty complicated. The size of the dots is in different units (points) then their position (data coordinates), so one would need to transform back and forth between the two. But I don't quite see the purpose anyways, because the scatter dot would hide any line behind it anyways, so a usual line plot would *look* the same, right?

Comment: @Sheldore, I added the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You could finagle with the sizes of the dots, but this is not how one should approach the problem. A better way would be to draw the dots after one draws the lines, so that the dots are placed on top.

This can be achieved with [zorder](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html). In your example, this would look like

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.scatter([0, 0, 0], [5, 3, 4], s=250, zorder=2)
plt.scatter([3, 3, 3], [5, 3, 4], s=350, zorder=2)

plt.arrow(0, 5, dx=3, dy=0, width=0.01, zorder=1)
plt.arrow(0, 3, dx=3, dy=0, width=0.01, zorder=1)
plt.arrow(0, 4, dx=3, dy=0, width=0.01, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

and this produces the plot

[image: a scatter plot in which the circles cover lines]

---

As an aside, you probably also are not looking for `arrow` if you're only looking to draw lines between points. You are just looking for `plot`.

Comment: I did thought about this, but with this approach I wouldn't be able to draw arrow head  if I am not mistaken?